# Computing the second Chern character on Kähler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $(X, \omega)$  be a compact Kähler manifold and $E$ a vector bundle on $X$ with hermitian metric $h$. Let also $F_h$ be the curvature of Chern connection on $(E, h)$. It is a $(1,1)$-form with coefficients in $\operatorname{End}(E)$.

In Simpson's paper "Higgs bundles and local systems" the following formula plays important role:
$$
\int_X \operatorname{Tr}(F_h \wedge F_h) \wedge \omega^{n-2} = C_1||F_h||_{L^2} - C_2||\Lambda F_h||_{L^2}
$$
for certain constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ (here $\Lambda$, as usual, is the hermitian-adjoint to the Lefschetz operator $L \colon \eta \mapsto \omega \wedge \eta$)

Indeed in Simpson's paper this equation is used not for a curvature of a unitary connection, but for a pseudocurvature of a hermitian metric on vector bundle endowed with flat connection . However, I believe it is not really important and the proves must be similar.

It seems that this relation holds in a general situation and follows from some standard Hodge theory. Although I don't understand how to prove it.

Simpson claims that this fact follows from "Riemann bilinear relations", but I don't understand what he really means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Chern-Weil theory for $τ$-Hermitian-Einstein structure we have

$$2\pi\tau\int_Xc_1(E)\wedge\frac{\omega^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-8\pi^2\int_Xch_2(E)\wedge\frac{\omega^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}=\tau\int_Xtr(\sqrt{-1}\Lambda_\omega F_H)\frac{\omega^n}{n!}+\int_Xtr(F_H\wedge F_H)\wedge\frac{\omega^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$$

Then from this you can get your identity. See this [lecture note](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/siu_reprints/dmv_book.pdf)